# Call to undefined function - Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length() in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-7

I am using Laravel v7 and PHP v7.2 for my project, getting this following error when I run the project.

> Error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

Comment: You are missing the vendor lib that serves this function. Did you run a `composer install` or even a `composer require illuminate/encryption` to require this vendor lib?

Comment: after running composer install getting same error ..then i tried running sudo curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php this command getting error like Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
 
The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

Comment: thats a proper error message. then you should fix your composer installation first ;-)

Comment: i have installed composer v2.1.8 properly but getting error [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]                                                                                                       
  The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disab
  le this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.